# Software integration and shared database for a master application

Tags: java, database, jakarta-ee, architecture, restful-architecture

I have 4 separate software systems which implemented separately using java EE, Spring,hibernate etc.I want to integrate all of them and build a master application. I want to have a single login as well. Now they have their own databases and I want to have a shared single database as well because they have some common information.

What is the best method which can be used to achieve this task with having minimum changes to currently implemented systems?

Do I have to implement a new service layer( eg: using JAX-RS) or something on top of new db to access the new shared database and provide all db access services with business logic to above software systems??

Answer (score 2):

**For DataBase:**

Spring/hibernate applications support connecting to one database by default. If you want to connect to multiple databases (own db + common db) then you will have to take care of database objects (Jdbc connection + pools + lifecycle/transaction management + other db initialisations) by yourself.

In my opinion DB connection+lifecycle initialisation yourself can be a huge pain and will take away your focus from solving real business cases. I would suggest using a single DB for the applications if possible. Most databases allow you to use file-per-table and even distribute the table files across multiple machines/servers (this is an optimisation).

**Code Unification**

For Unifying the code base into one (I assume you want to unify the codebases), you can make each application a separate module each with its own resource path. For example if you have Service1, Service2 and Service3 then in your new code base all your Service1 resources will be hosted inside /service1 path, Service2 resources inside /service2 path and so on. To do this you will simply need to modify the Path specifiers in your resource files (usually an `@Path` annotation).

***Q:*** How to change all the api calls to these services since their path changed?

**A:** Now if you already pickup the paths to api call for these services from a config file then its great, just change the paths in your config file. Else you can actually start using this config approach, and specify something as below:

In your config file:

```
api-paths: {
    service1: /service1/
    service2: /service2/
    ...
}
```

**Config Unification**

You can put all your configs in a single file which most frameworks support. Another option to look at is putting separate config files for each service. For 2nd option take a look at [TypeSafe Config Lib](https://github.com/typesafehub/config). It allows you to use multiple config files with overrides.

**Note:** In case codebase unification is not needed then use a reverse proxy like nginx. Its just how huge websites like google/fb work. You see a single domain which hides all the microservices behind layers of reverse proxies and a CDN.

**For Auth/Login**

You can do this in a servlet filter. In your config have an exclusion list, these excluded paths can be accessed without login. For example the /login path must in exclusion list so people can access the login page without login first. Now your servlet filter can implement a simple client cookie + server side session store based auth. You will need a password store as well.

The login flow will be like:

1. User open /login page
2. User enters username+password (credentials)
3. Server receives request for login with credentials. Server checks credentials against its own credential/password store.
4. If successful then server sends response back to client to set a cookie with some expiry time. If failed then send Http Unauthorised response.
5. Server stores the cookie in its session store as well (cookies will be stored per-client, user1+chrome=1 cookie, user1+firefox=another cookie, user2+any=another set of cookies)
6. In further requests the client sends the cookie and server (the servlet filter) verifies against its session store. If verification passes then server allows the api call to work.
7. If cookie expired or no cookie in request then redirect user to /login. Continue from step-1.

**Note:** Always hash your credentials on client end before sending on network. On server side store only hashed credentials, no raw text passwords. Also if security is paramount then look at salting your credentials as well.

Comment: Thank you very much for your assistance. I got a good idea about how to get an approach to my problem. It would be great if you can give a little explanation about the module. Did you mean a module which same as modules that we use in maven? Also if we use a reverse proxy without code unification can I use a single database for all softwares?

Comment: @heshan : Yes by modules I meant maven modules (or gradle modules if you favor gradle). A single database can be used even if your apps/services are running separately. So yes, reverse proxy + single db will work as well. IMO reverse proxy like nodejs/nginx which take care of login will be fastest to implement. When you said they have common info in their db do you mean common tables? Or common info logically but no common tables?

Comment: I meant the common tables. As an example details of the employees with their IDs. I have to maintain a common single employee table for all applications. As I think there may be some consistency problems if I use separate databases for each application.

Answer (score 0):

I think a good aproach for this is to have a Look at netflix technology Stack. There is a project called zuul which Acts as reverse proxy. This proxy can route incoming requests to your underlying Services. This proxy can be the frontdoor to your services where every request only can pass throu if it is authenticated. 
Hope this will help a bit.